# Removing the "as" keywords from this typescript code

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am trying to remove the `as` keywords from this typescript code so it can look better. It has this method named `update` where I am trying a smarter way to structure the sanitizing, validation and attribution, but it seems that it wouldn't work with typescript, so I am looking for help to implement this while trying the best to maintain the code structure.

This is the code:

```js
export class AccessProfile {

    id!: number;
    active!: boolean;
    name!: string;
    createdAt!: Date;
    createdBy!: User | null;
    createdFrom!: SystemModule;
    updatedAt!: Date;
    updatedBy!: User | null;
    updatedFrom!: SystemModule;
    hierarchy!: number | null;
    permissions!: Set<string>;


    public update(
        {
            updatedFrom,
            updatedBy = null,
            name,
            active,
            hierarchy,
            permissions
        }: {
            updatedFrom: SystemModule,
            updatedBy?: DiphycUser | null,
            name?: string,
            active?: boolean,
            hierarchy?: number | null,
            permissions?: Set<string>,
        }
    ) {
        const changedValues = new Set();


        if (name !== undefined) {
            name = AccessProfile.sanitizeName(name);

            if (this.name !== name) {
                AccessProfile.validateName(name);
                changedValues.add("name");
            }
        }

        if (active !== undefined && this.active !== active) {
            changedValues.add("active");
        }

        if (hierarchy !== undefined) {
            hierarchy = AccessProfile.sanitizeHierarchy(hierarchy);

            if (this.hierarchy !== hierarchy) {
                AccessProfile.validateHierarchy(hierarchy);
                changedValues.add("hierarchy");
            }
        }

        if (
            permissions !== undefined
            && !permissionsAreEqual(permissions, this.permissions)
        ) {
            changedValues.add("permissions");
        }

        if (changedValues.has("hierarchy") && changedValues.has("permissions")) {
            AccessProfile.validateHierarchyAndPermissions({
                hierarchy: hierarchy as number | null,
                permissions: permissions as Set<string>
            });
        } else if (changedValues.has("hierarchy")) {
            AccessProfile.validateHierarchyAndPermissions({
                hierarchy: hierarchy as number | null,
                permissions: this.permissions
            });
        } else if (changedValues.has("permissions")) {
            AccessProfile.validateHierarchyAndPermissions({
                hierarchy: this.hierarchy,
                permissions: permissions as Set<string>
            });
        }

        this.updatedFrom = updatedFrom;
        this.updatedBy = updatedBy;

        if (changedValues.has("name")) this.name = name as string;
        if (changedValues.has("active")) this.active = active as boolean;
        if (changedValues.has("hierarchy")) this.hierarchy = hierarchy as number | null;
        if (changedValues.has("permissions")) this.permissions = permissions as Set<string>;

        this.updatedAt = new Date();

        return this;
    }

}
```

Comment: Let's take `name` for example. You declare it as `name?: string` which means it can be either `undefined` or `string`, but never check if it's `undefined` and then just cast is as `string`. So it still can throw error in runtime, you just lie to typescript that it won't

Comment: Please [edit] this code to be a [mre] that we can copy and paste into our own IDEs and get to work, where the only problems present are the ones you're asking about.  That means you should, among other things, remove or replace any undeclared values or types (e.g., what is `User`, what is `SystemModule`, what is `sanitizeName`, etc).  Ideally you would just remove anything that isn't directly germane to the question, stripping it down to the minimum example necessary to reproduce the problem you're trying to solve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am looking for help to implement this while trying the best to maintain the code structure.

That code would actually benefit from some restructuring: the logical flow is not easy to read and I will simply assume it is correct/exhaustive (as it seems at a cursory read), it is also written in such a way as not to leverage the type guards in TS, which is the very reason why all those type casts are  eventually needed.

That said, all uses of `as` in that code are to remove `undefined` from the type, so, to get rid of those explicit casts while keeping the code structure unchanged, the [Non-null Assertion Operator (Postfix `!`)](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#non-null-assertion-operator-postfix-) might be what you're looking for.

For example:

```
hierarchy as number | null
```

becomes:

```
hierarchy!
```

Just please NOTE that the `!` operator also gets rid of `null`, not just of `undefined`: so it does the trick *in this case*, i.e. with this specific function as written, but the "solution" is *not* robust to changes to the code, since from that point on TS just doesn't see the `null` in the type of the interested values -- but not changing the code is one of the two requirements you have given.  IOW, it is a minimal hack for a bit more readability, but the advice remains the code better be rewritten to some extent.

Comment: The postfix ! gets rid of undefined and null, I was only trying to get rid of the undefined.

But I have tried a different approach. I made a backup object to register all the previous values and made the changes directly to the properties inside a try catch. If something goes wrong, the "catch" part will use the backup object to reassign the previous values. I am trying to maintain the instance´s state as consistent as possible, making the changes only if they should be made. What do you think of this approach?

Comment: @Cristofer  <<The postfix `!` gets rid of undefined and null>>  That's right, but it does the trick in this case, of getting rid of those explicit casts: I have expanded my answer to explain this point.

Comment: <<I made a backup object to register all the previous values and made the changes directly to the properties inside a try catch. If something goes wrong, the "catch" part will use the backup object to reassign the previous values.>>  Two considerations on that:

Comment: 1) (If I understand you correctly) In case of error, that just behaves as a no-op, i.e. does nothing, and user code is none the wiser: typically that is not a good scheme, a validation exception should be thrown, and user code let to decide if and how to handle it.

Comment: 2) <<I am trying to maintain the instance's state as consistent as possible, making the changes only if they should be made. What do you think of this approach?>>  That idea is OK, but here is the canonical structure of such a function: 1.1. validate the single arguments; 1.2. validate inter-argument ("cross") constraints; 2. possibly use those (now valid) arguments to build new (valid) data; 3. use the data -- where 2 can be mixed/fused with 1 to streamline the flow a little bit, the essential point being that, when you get to 3, *all* values are (recognized by TS as) of a valid type.

Comment: That said, overall please consider that if you now decide that the code should indeed be restructured, then it is a new question...

Comment: This is the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77906467/figuring-out-the-best-way-to-update-state-of-an-object-in-oop-in-typescript) to the question

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, your function parameters are defined as optional (like `name?: string` or `hierarchy?: number | null`), so their type is actually not `string` or `number | null` but `string | undefined` and `number | null | undefined`. Also your controlflow does not handle the case where `name === undefined`, so TS has no possibility of narrowing down from `string | undefined` to `string`.

But in the `AccessProfile` class, the `name` is defined as `name: string`. So when you then for instance try to assign `this.name = name;`, you are actually trying to assign a value that might be `undefined` to variable that must not be `undefined`. And that is not allowed.

There are some possibilites to fix this issue:

1. You define some default behaviour, for the case that `name` is really `undefined`. I know, you implicitly do this by checking `if (changedValues.has("name"))`, but the TS controlflow analysis isn't capable of using this to narrow down the type from `string | undefined` to `string`. For instance you could do the following

   ```
   if (name !== undefined) {
     ...
   } else {
     name = this.name;  //assign it the current value, which must be a string
   }
   ```
2. You explicitly override the typechecking system with `name as string`  (like you currently do)
3. You use the `!` [non-null assertion operator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-0.html#non-null-assertion-operator)  like `this.name = name!`  Ie explicitly telling TS, that the value is not `undefined` even if it was (but this can't happen in your case though)
4. Move the assignment `this.name = name;` inside the block, where you check the presence of the `name` parameter. This way you can also get rid of the `changedValues` set and you code will be much cleaner and shorter.

   ```
    if (name !== undefined) {
       //do your checks if changed
       ...
       //and if yes do the assignement here
       this.name = name;  //name cannot be undefined here but must be a string
    }
   ```

I personally, would go with number 4 ... And of course, this applies to the other properties in a similar manner.