# Figuring out the best way to update state of an object in OOP in Typescript

Tags: typescript, oop, backend

I am using Object Oriented Programming in my application and I am trying to figure out the best way to change state of an object while maintaining its consistency. I have written a code that does that, but is there a better way of doing it? Is there any pattern that someone has already discovered while writing in OOP?

This is the code I've written:

```js
export class AccessProfile {

    id!: number;
    active!: boolean;
    name!: string;
    createdAt!: Date;
    createdBy!: string | null;
    createdFrom!: SystemModule;
    updatedAt!: Date;
    updatedBy!: string | null;
    updatedFrom!: SystemModule;
    environment!: Environment;
    hierarchy!: number | null;
    permissions!: Set<string>;


    public update(
        {
            updatedFrom,
            updatedBy = null,
            name,
            active,
            hierarchy,
            permissions
        }: {
            updatedFrom: SystemModule,
            updatedBy?: string | null,
            name?: string,
            active?: boolean,
            hierarchy?: number | null,
            permissions?: Set<string>,
        }
    ) {

        const backup = {
            name: this.name,
            active: this.active,
            hierarchy: this.hierarchy,
            permissions: this.permissions
        };

        try {

            if (name !== undefined) {
                name = AccessProfile.sanitizeName(name);

                if (this.name !== name) {
                    AccessProfile.validateName(name);
                    this.name = name;
                }
            }

            if (active !== undefined && this.active !== active) {
                this.active = active;
            }

            if (hierarchy !== undefined) {
                hierarchy = AccessProfile.sanitizeHierarchy(hierarchy);

                if (this.hierarchy !== hierarchy) {
                    AccessProfile.validateHierarchy(hierarchy);
                    this.hierarchy = hierarchy;
                }
            }

            if (
                permissions !== undefined
                && !permissionsAreEqual(permissions, this.permissions)
            ) {
                this.permissions = permissions;
            }

            if (this.hierarchy !== backup.hierarchy && this.permissions !== backup.permissions) {
                AccessProfile.validateHierarchyAndPermissions({
                    hierarchy: this.hierarchy,
                    permissions: this.permissions
                });
            } else if (this.hierarchy !== backup.hierarchy) {
                AccessProfile.validateHierarchyAndPermissions({
                    hierarchy: this.hierarchy,
                    permissions: backup.permissions
                });
            } else if (this.permissions !== backup.permissions) {
                AccessProfile.validateHierarchyAndPermissions({
                    hierarchy: backup.hierarchy,
                    permissions: this.permissions
                });
            }

            this.updatedFrom = updatedFrom;
            this.updatedBy = updatedBy;

            this.updatedAt = new Date();
            return this;
        } catch (err) {

            this.name = backup.name;
            this.active = backup.active;
            this.hierarchy = backup.hierarchy;
            this.permissions = backup.permissions;

            throw err;
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: If I understand correctly what your after, In your `update` function you create a new object say called `newState`,  do your updates to the new state keeping your consistency  / validation etc. and when happy `Object.assign(this, newState)`  Doing this you don't need to keep a copy of backup etc.

Answer (score 0):

> I am trying to figure out the best way to change state of an object while maintaining its consistency.

I'd say the canonical and indeed cleanest way to approach that is to structure your `update` method in two phases: 1) validate and adjust arguments (and throw on invalid data); 2) assign (now valid) data to instance properties.  Below is a minimal example, with few more suggestions in the code.

Incidentally, working with single arguments/variables vs objects and their properties is almost exactly equivalent and the guiding principle should be readability: that said, an `Object.assign` can indeed save few lines of code, on the other hand it does not allow optimizing by only assigning to changed properties.

```
export interface ProfileData {
  hierarchy: number | null;
  permissions: Set<string>;
}

export class Profile implements ProfileData {

  hierarchy: ProfileData["hierarchy"];
  permissions: ProfileData["permissions"];

  /**
   * @throws {Error} Invalid argument
   * @throws {Error} Invalid arguments
   */
  constructor({
    hierarchy,
    permissions,
  }: ProfileData) {
    // We SHOULD validate data here as well, which
    // hints at extracting a data validation function
    // to be used here as well as in `update`...

    this.hierarchy = hierarchy;
    this.permissions = permissions;
  }

  /**
   * @throws {Error} Invalid argument
   * @throws {Error} Invalid arguments
   */
  public update({
    hierarchy,
    permissions,
  }: Partial<ProfileData>) {
    // (1) Validate and adjust data:

    // (1.1) Validate and adjust data values:

    if (typeof hierarchy === "undefined") {
      hierarchy = this.hierarchy;
    }
    else {
      hierarchy = Profile.sanitizeHierarchy(hierarchy);

      Profile.validateHierarchy(hierarchy);
    }

    if (typeof permissions === "undefined") {
      permissions = this.permissions;
    }

    // (1.2) Cross-validate data:

    Profile.validateHierarchyAndPermissions(hierarchy, permissions);

    // (2) Assign (now valid) data:

    // These optimizations, skipping assignments,
    // usually are overkill, anyway here we go:

    if (hierarchy !== this.hierarchy) {
      this.hierarchy = hierarchy;
    }

    if (!Profile.permissionsAreEqual(permissions, this.permissions)) {
      this.permissions = permissions;
    }

    return this;
  }

  static permissionsAreEqual(
    permissions1: ProfileData["permissions"],
    permissions2: ProfileData["permissions"],
  ): boolean {
    throw "NOT YET IMPLEMENTED";
  }

  // There is a *smell* associated with a `validate` that
  // takes in input the same type as in output: if there is
  // a `validate`, then the type of input supposedly is not
  // the same as the type of valid data... and, along those
  // lines, the validation functions below should rather
  // return an `asserts` type.  But I didn't have enough info
  // to fully close the circle here, also considering that you
  // have made no such distinction in your `update` function...

  static sanitizeHierarchy(
    hierarchy: ProfileData["hierarchy"],
  ): ProfileData["hierarchy"] {
    throw "NOT YET IMPLEMENTED";
  }

  /**
   * @throws {Error} Invalid argument
   */
  static validateHierarchy(
    hierarchy: ProfileData["hierarchy"],
  ): void | never {
    throw "NOT YET IMPLEMENTED";
  }

  /**
   * @throws {Error} Invalid arguments
   */
  static validateHierarchyAndPermissions(
    hierarchy: ProfileData["hierarchy"],
    permissions: ProfileData["permissions"],
  ): void | never {
    throw "NOT YET IMPLEMENTED";
  }
}
```

[Link to playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBASwHY2FAZgQwMbDgBSgnQQBtgARTGTOAbwCg44ALBNTKbFgTwC44SAK4BbAEZo4AH0FDSpANxM4YNCIQBnDQghINAgMrAYAHg0woyAOYA+JQF8GDUJFhxspTFoJES5RCJg5CLAKBo+xGSU1LSMymwcXLwChJHkVDQA2gBECVCc3DzZALpKzKpQ6lo6eim+URmYORVV2roaJUrKAPQAVL3KcL1wAAIwLEQA7uF0AKJQRFD2cACSSABumKQIACZwnFaioTCDw2MTENP084vLa5vbewdHYafdytjtFkLYMNAAFIxmMw8gVeAAaQYqNSaNp6SHMex1NLRGgASnoUO63TgAHU8AYABIAeQAqgAZChwB67ah4HYxVhoPBeOCTYDycFstjcLE4thhfbwUAWHAwaz7OAMmjUra08W6ODoIRIX41PlwP5wCRwIQaYB7FjM-bhdnyE2IJBwAAGQjA0uA1oAdC6nMDNWwNE7QUkeHAALysdj5X1lYHjTROlqwmrhQPR6rtMOOHr9U6jcZTGY3aB3DZyp5QQ4hFDp85Z64LXOrfOPfZFl4wDRvZRgIRibbYXX2umAqE+woI4EJuEaIdIgiccVbEypPyozA2DFA4HYuD-ACMGIAagW6fskE8dgArPXwaWYPhu1c4zdOrdwXePfeYQ-7E9nqWMh5CYD6a-MAg6DrjAPCqMQQaJIUAb+oG2QqjswAkEgBrZMuUIgsGYJ+oGEZegOvBhoiUIcvqmLuphUG8AGETzk6Givgg4oAF7AISWG+v8BE8GiXQUbRUROjSDrsVRPBcRxhS8VCKbukBIFgcAEEjrGMFwQhSHIKh6H8Sp7Q0XhUYwomehEXAsk3uuG5OgATBiADCRBaAAtMJ+4XleUJzoJbmoKJIaFAAgoe+DGaOEliVyel6NJGr-HZcCBdUVhWv8SCXLKjwYh5AFwGuAAqRpkRAYDiuozHULGXIaAA1ggYBgBKXjaClJZNkOzBrnqQhbKQfqcHgEDrGgdWcgePCTJgfpGlAeDsnAVgQJ5cnARFAXUQAhLBHqRtxOkUYZ3E0dxZkWYBq0bd55BGZUMbtIFs2zAAjj1pD-NFY47V6H1ovt7qGR9NEfaduWzTAQhQFaeHJte5iVV2H0PcAz2vf8UIfRuyLzo0zRhbGJQddCt0mRoNlYw0MS48To4E8oaICGIEAQOQr7keGFyTHA2QAHLEvlcAAJqzPzKwALL4OSsyi7M3P5bMFDZDDPQ4oVxqaJKvQaCE8jDM1EDYAgdJ7JMTEsJK1q+Y6HrUMrmqYDVf6WpabbwOMeAMSEmqKRayBwBAQgwC7AjyW7s2IM2nU4rQFt7qg1pcm7UNGl7qh+8ByAu3AGh2pA+o7H14eCBAJyRx67uYJ7rJuyng3AcJX40C6ToHjsXJbLoVgehA+q29sKGfdXvk1EqKpqvpEikBlGgsP7pB7Pkoe22DENWqz1rNWgTbWjXzdwAAQgHqxSrsSAAOTwCwmDDXAoT+1YZvIOgEC21qyryH6Hjd3g1cG1w-gzcANupANAQHcO0XYaAJTjGoHAHg-tbaX2viITAiEi5Zx+GbHYmhxSqgVFaX2cCIY2jtA6beypcE1CbrDGg4ouwMSQExBArF-LYTRu6bi5N0iU1yJJXgtNmD0wElwrIPCxIlDZswTMGUeZ80FsLVY4tJbS1lvLRWygLJ9AGMCM4UirhzCrEsGs9dnhtRbMwOGtDMryjYrw8S-ZbGcIXDkbi-C4CCPWBAXY0hBDAGGlACRHophc15vzIWItFFSxlnLBWStOppm0RmDm2YDF5mMQ2NqEdmC9HeOYmhCAuyWxYb6YKOxQrU1jGw4EHChFONEetIoxRCYfUcTjbIH1XHuM8XsGQKE-EBN0cE2RYSFES0iSomJ6iGCOCAA)